# Erro comparação de Strings java

Tags: java, string, jsp, comparação

Tenho a seguinte situação.

Recebo uma string que esta no localStorage da aplicação em uma variavel javascript.

```
<script>
    var sendForm = localStorage.getItem('f');
</script>
```

Essa mesma string eu passo para uma variavel java para realizar os devidos procedimentos que irei precisar.

```
<% 
    String id_formulario = "";
    id_formulario = "<script>document.write(sendForm)</script>"; 
%>
```

Para realizar testes eu mostro essa string com um

```
<%
    out.print(id_formulario);
%>
```

E tudo bem! ela é a string exata que estava no localStorage, porém quando eu tento comparar ela com qualquer string IGUAL o java não reconhece que são iguais e simplesmente ignora.

```
<%
    if(id_formulario.equals("QUALQUERVALOR")){
        out.print("É igual!!!");
    }
%>
```

Porque isso está acontecendo? Já tentei de tudo e não consigo de forma nenhuma resolver esse problema!!

Comment: Já tentei equalsIgnoreCase, ==, ===, equals mas tudo isso da como se não fosse igual a string que eu peguei do localStorage

Comment: Ao mostrar o length() do valor recebido e o que eu esperava deu uma diferença que acabei visualizando o problema. O valor que recebi tinha 41 caracteres enquanto o que eu esperava tinha 22.

Comment: quando você manda escrever a variável `id_formulario` sozinha, por exemplo, ele esta do modo como você esperava?

Answer (score 0):

Variáveis javascript ficam no front-end enquanto os códigos "<% code %>" são executados no back-end antes de enviar as devidas informações.

Uma coisa é você replicar dados que já são por padrão adicionados ao javascript na compilação do seu back-end, outro são dados que estão na "localStorage" do navegador de seu cliente.

Após a requisição chegar no seu "cliente", os códigos "<% %>" não existem mais, pois já foram processados pelo seu servidor.

No caso, seu servidor ao compilar, não teve acesso ao localStorage:

```
<script> var sendForm = localStorage.getItem('f'); </script>
```

Não conseguindo processar corretamente o resto do código que necessitava desta informação.

Comment: Então ele acabou armazenando na variavel id_formulario o valor literal de "<script>document.write(sendForm)</script>", Acabei de ver que o erro era esse, mas aproeitando Kelvin, como eu poderia receber a variavel do localStorage em uma variavel JSP?

Comment: @user63185 na chamada desta "tela" assim dizer, você pode requerir que o client envie este dados. Ou seja, se você está abrindo uma tela de cliente, você necessita do ID, e assim você sempre vai mandar o ID na chamada Http desta tela, sendo ela POST ou GET... Então no seu problema, como o servidor necessita deste dado, você passaria este dado também na chamada desta tela, como aconteceria com um ID de usuário.

Comment: Pensei nisso, o problema @Kelvin é que o funcionamento é o seguinte, Tenho um formulário que os dados são enviados para um arquivo jsp e este que estou falando é um outro arquivo jsp, que é uma página de resposta, então "não teria" como enviar o id para lá entendeu? Estou estudando a possibilidade de trabalhar com cookies já que o java consegue manipular diretamente eles.

Answer (score 0):

Se o que você disse esta correto.

> porém quando eu tento comparar ela com qualquer string IGUAL o java não reconhece que são iguais e simplesmente ignora

Então a ferramenta que esta usando não esta compilando, ou esta tentando em javascript pensando que é igual a Java

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido,

A atribuição que eu estava fazendo de uma variável javascript para uma jsp estava errada, da maneira que estava escrita o java entendia que o valor da variável serial literalmente "document.write(sendForm)". Então nunca serial igual a algo que eu estivesse esperando.

Solução,

O java não trabalha com localStorage, porém trabalha com cookies, então mudei de localStorage para cookies e agora funcionou normalmente!

Obrigado a todos que responderam, no final foi apenas uma pesquisa que me retornou uma resposta errada e causou tanto problema!